# ASP.NET MVC 5 Repository pattern with OWIN

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

In MVC 4 I ended up overriding the controller factory to allow my `ApplicationDbContext` to be injected into each controller as it was instantiated. I was sure that throughout my requests I would never have two references to my `ApplicationDbContext` which ensured I didn't have any multithreading issues.

Now that MVC 5 is here, what's the proper way of implementing the repository pattern with OWIN? I've heard with OWIN that it creates a new UserManager / ApplicationDbContext per request. If this is true, then I would like to use the database context in my controllers / repositories. Is it possible to pass the database context into a controller? (Something to the lines of `HttpResponse.GetOwinContext.Environment["owin.DatabaseContext"]` ??)

There seems to be a half-finished question here that doesn't have an answer to the question: [OWIN DbContext and a single DbContext for all of my Repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827376/owin-dbcontext-and-a-single-dbcontext-for-all-of-my-repositories). (also one here: [Owin Context to use a single instance per request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388656/owin-context-to-use-a-single-instance-per-request?rq=1)) Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is true, you can setup your context to use the same instance of a class by using the method CreatePerOwinContext, so for the UserManager / ApplicationDbContext you can set them up in the Startup.ConfigureAuth method to something like this:

```
// Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
```

and when you need your dependency you can use GetUserManager method for example to retrieve the ApplicationUserManager object. so something like this:

```
var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
```

Also, some Ioc containers like Autofac supports OWIN integration, you can refer to [this](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#owin-integration) webpage for more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Omar, is it possible to get this ApplicationDbContext when I am creating constructors? Such that I can grab this context, create the proper repository, and pass in the repository into the controller?

Comment: Well, if you have the OWIN context then you can call context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>() for example to get the ApplicationDbContext for the current request after you registered that using app.CreatePerOwinContext in the Startup, you can have a look into my article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/742532/Using-Web-API-Individual-User-Account-plus-CORS-En and check how do I call context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>() when I initialize ApplicationUserManager class.